# how to for loop object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, loops, express

I want to loop through req.body payload object in a nodejs application and get the array object with SplitType = 'FLAT'. So after I finish looping through the array object I'll push the value into an empty array. I'm getting an error saying the SplitType is not defined. below is the object array that I want to loop through.

```
{
"ID": 13092,
"Amount": 4500,
"Currency": "NGN",
"CustomerEmail": "anon8@customers.io",
"SplitInfo": [
    {
        "SplitType": "FLAT",
        "SplitValue": 450,
        "SplitEntityId": "LNPYACC0019"
    },
    {
        "SplitType": "RATIO",
        "SplitValue": 3,
        "SplitEntityId": "LNPYACC0011"
    },
    {
        "SplitType": "PERCENTAGE",
        "SplitValue": 3,
        "SplitEntityId": "LNPYACC0015"
    },
    {
        "SplitType": "RATIO",
        "SplitValue": 2,
        "SplitEntityId": "LNPYACC0016"
    },
    {
        "SplitType": "FLAT",
        "SplitValue": 2450,
        "SplitEntityId": "LNPYACC0029"
    },
    {
        "SplitType": "PERCENTAGE",
        "SplitValue": 10,
        "SplitEntityId": "LNPYACC0215"
    },
]
```

}

Here is the for loop code

```
for (let i = 0; i = splitInfo.length; i++) {
    if(splitInfo[i].SplitType === 'FLAT') {
      result.initialBalance = flat(initialBalance, splitInfo.SplitValue);
      result.SplitBreakdown.push({
        SplitEntityId: splitInfo.SplitEntityId,
        Amount: splitInfo.SplitValue
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: `i = splitInfo.length;` <---- wrong condition check.

Comment: pick from req.boby like `const { SplitInfo } = req.body` and loop through it and follow above @epascarello comment.

Comment: Why are you assigning `i` the value of `splitInfo.length`?  That will only exit your loop when the length is falsey, i.e. when `splitInfo.length` reaches 0.  That might make sense if you were removing elements from `splitInfo` on each iteration, but you're not, so I agree with others that your loop exit condition is likely wrong.  Consider `for (const item of splitInfo) { if (item.SplitType` ...

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is wrong, I think you mean:

```
for (let i = 0; i < splitInfo.length; i++) {
```